# Словарь в Живом поиске на ajax - php?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Всем привет.

Реализовал живой поиск на ajax php. http://cash-back.kz/. Для примера введите пылесос.

Работает все нормально. Но вот я наткнулся на проблему с поиском по товаров. Он сейчас ищет по таблице product и показывает наименование продуктов. А если у меня будет 1000 пылесосов, то я на экран все 1000 должен выводить? или выведу только 10 а остальные у меня не будут показывать, из за этого будут недовольны клиенты.

Есть решение, создать таблицу vocabulary и туда записывать словарь продуктов. Например Пылесос, Монитор, компьютер и т д. Только как вот можно заполнить этот словарь?

1. При добавлении товара пусть они добавляют ключевые теги. Типо наименование товара пылесос Zanusii 2010, а ключевой тег Пылесос?
2. Или скачать где нибудь готовый словарь?

Подскажите как лучше это сделать. СПАСИБО!

Comment: По мере набора ключевых слов пользователем, выводите ограниченное количество товаров, но при этом, добавьте внизу ссылку аля "*Все результаты поиска*". Так реализовано на многих сайтах.
![Реальный пример][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/yXD1TkY.jpg

Comment: Отпадает сразу. Получается какая то газета. Надо сделать по примеру google. У него нету такой функции.

Comment: @duddeniska, про какую газету и какую функцию вы говорите, я лично не совсем понял, но google выводит список результатов, разбивая их по определенному кол-ву на страницы. Однако в "живом поиске", постранички там тоже нет, а результат выводится так же ограничено, по релевантности и с учетом многих обстоятельств: ваше геоположение, предпочитаемый язык, прошлые ваши запросы и т.д. Хотите как у google? Кто ж против.

Comment: По поводу вашего 1-го пункта: создайте отдельную таблицу, назовите её, например, type_product и вносите туда все необходимые типы товаров (пылесос, стиральная машина, телефон), а в таблице product добавьте поле type_product_id с соответствующей ссылкой на таблицу type_product. А при выборе нужных товаров просто проверяйте условие WHERE type_product_id = type_product.id.

Но по большому счету, искать напрямую из базы не есть хорошо, лучше куда-то выгружать все возможные варианты для поиска (например, в json или xml) и искать уже в них.

Comment: если человек ввел "телефон" то показывайте ему ссылку на категорию мобильных телефонов. не нужно ему выводить того, чего он не ищет. 

Вот я зашел на сайт и у вас куча разделов. Я не буду искать во "все разделы", я наберу просто в поисковике "телефоны" и буду очень сильно надеяться, что вы мне в результате покажете ссылку на раздела, а не какой то левый телефон